# Codeigniter : mp4 video won't upload, no error

Tags: php, codeigniter, video, upload

I'm creating a form to upload video file, but I have a strange error.

My form is like this:

```
<div style="color : red;"><?php echo $error;?></div>    
<?php echo form_open_multipart('data_center/ajout_ressource/formulaire_video'); ?>
   //various input text fields...

   <input type="file" name="video">
   <input type="submit" value="Ajouter cette ressource" />
</form>±
```

My method to get upload is (it's inside something to check if the rest of the form is ok):

```
  $dir = './assets/video/';
  $config['upload_path'] = $dir;
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'avi|flv|wmv|mpeg|mp3|mp4';
  $config['max_size']   = '102400';
  $this->load->library('upload',$config);
  if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('video')){
     $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
     $this->load->view('data_center/ajout_video', $error);
  } else {
     redirect('data_center/data_center/','refresh');
  }
```

Concerning mime types, I think it's ok:

```
'mp4'   =>      'video/mp4',
'wmv'   =>     array('video/wmv', 'video/x-ms-wmv', 'flv-application/octet-stream', 'application/octet-stream'),
'flv'   =>     array('video/flv', 'video/x-flv', 'flv-application/octet-stream', 'application/octet-stream'),
'avi'   =>  'video/x-msvideo',
```

When I try to upload a mp4 file it automatically redirect me (although I'm not sure it's a redirection) to the form, unfilled and no error message, even if I comment the lines in case of upload failure not to load the view again or if the rest of the form is uncorrect (it should not attempt to upload the video and load the form pre-filled).
Whereas for example, if I put the wrong type of file, I can see the error message ('The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed' for example), or if the form is wrong I can see the error of the form.
Finally, I must add that I modified php.ini to authorize such big files, and that I did pretty much the same thing with a form for pictures (jpg,jpeg,png...) which works perfectly but also redirect me to an unfilled form if I try to upload a .mp4 file.
**Edit:** I just downloaded an flv video to try, and it uploaded perfectly fine, but its size was less than 8mb (default config), and a 40mb flv file had the same problem as the mp4 file, although I changed my config in php.ini for 100mb

Comment: file size problem? vid files tend to be **MUCH** larger than images, so being able to upload a .jpg and not .mp4 doesn't mean much for your code. you cannot change php's file upload limits from within php, because the php code doing so will only fire AFTER the upload has been attempted and failed - you need to make sure the php.ini limits are set high enough to allow your .mp4 in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectively you have to change *two* parameters in PHP ini file

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

But you may also want to change the apache abuse protection parameter (100M)

```
LimitRequestBody 1073741824
```

And by another hand, PHP have a time limit too of 30 sec per script, so your script will die at 30 seconds of running.

You may also want to increase the time to be sure your script does not die meanwhile you are uploading, copying etc,

```
set_time_limit(600);  // 10 minutos execution
```

Comment: I changed my php.ini file for post_max_size (upload_max_filesize was already changed) and put a set_time_limit(600), it seems to be a problem of size, but I don't know where to change the LimitRequestBody, and I'm not sure where to call the set_time_limit() function

Comment: LimitRequestBody should be in the httpd.conf or better (depends a *lot* of your apache config) in extras/php.conf or similar. full path is generally /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and /etc/httpd/conf/extras/php.conf, depends again your configuration. BTW, is your PHP on Apache or on another web server ?

Comment: set_time_limit is a PHP function, you should put at the beginning of your code that upload the file

Comment: Ok, it was just not working because I did not restart the apache server, now your config fits perfectly, thank you