# Codeigniter video uploads not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, video

I am using following code to do a video uploading.

```
<?php

class upload_videos extends Admin_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }

    function index () {
        $this->load->view('admin/upload_form', array('error'=> ''));
    }

    function do_upload() {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'mov|mpeg|mp3|avi';
        $config['max_size']= '';
        $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors() . ' hi');
            $this->load->view('admin/upload_form', $error);
        } else {
            echo 'asasas';
            $data = array('upload_data'=>$this->upload->data());
            $this->load->view('admin/upload_success', $data);
        }
    }


}
```

My problem is when i try to upload a mp4 video it shows me

> string(9) "video/mp4"

message. it does not fall into else part and video is not get uploaded. Could someone please help me to do this.
**note: I have set the max file sizes in php.ini and note I have tried setting mime type as `$this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]); var_dump($this->file_type); die();` as well**

**Edited**

I changed the above code to upload images, It gave me the same result. Looks like nothing can be uploaded using my code.

Comment: make sure the folder exist and permissions are set to `777`.

Answer (score 1):

I also meet the same issue. But now its working fine for me.

Efectively you have to change *two* parameters in PHP ini file

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

But you may also want to change the apache abuse protection parameter (100M)

```
LimitRequestBody 1073741824
```

And by another hand, PHP have a time limit too of 30 sec per script, so your script will die at 30 seconds of running.

You may also want to increase the time to be sure your script does not die meanwhile you are uploading, copying etc,

```
set_time_limit(600);  // 10 minutos execution
```

Found this answer from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716430/codeigniter-mp4-video-wont-upload-no-error)

Comment: Tried this. Still having the problem. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

add `mp4` format to `allowed_types`, as:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'mov|mpeg|mp3|avi|mp4';
```

and add mime type for mp4 in your `config/mimes.php` if does not exist already, as:

```
'mp4' => array('video/mp4', 'application/octet-stream')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Tried this.  still no luck