# Upload a video other than do_upload() function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, video

I'm using to upload a video by function  `do_upload()` but this function uploads only the MP4, ogg, webm, avi but not `flv , 3gp & some files`.

I added mime type of flv in mime.php

```
video/x-flv 
video/3gpp
```

but it's displaying as follows

```
The file type you attending to upload isn't allowed
```

how to upload these files or how to use other function replacing the `do_upload()`

Please help me....

Answer (score 1):

Add mime type in the config/mimes.php

```
'flv'    => array('video/x-flv', 'flv-application/octet-stream', 'application/octet-stream'),
'mp4' => 'video/mp4',
'3gp' => 'video/3gpp'
```

And try this [Codeigniter : mp4 video won't upload, no error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716430/codeigniter-mp4-video-wont-upload-no-error)

Comment: I tried as you mentioned in above.
But It's not working to do that upload.
Again it's displaying same error as shown in my question.....